# How to cover custom exception when catching an exception in mockito in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, code-coverage, powermockito

For eg.

```
try {
    // Some code
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new CustomDefineException(e);
}
```

I want to write mockito coverage statement for the catch block. How can that be done? I'm new on mockito framework.

Comment: To get coverage you have to set up a test case that causes an `IOException` to be thrown. The code you show does not throw an IOException though so it's impossible for the code in the catch block to run.

Comment: Ohh.. so you mean until or unless an exception is thrown or an explicit test case is written for the exception, it won't be covered?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works

Answer (score 0):

So basically as per Joni, we can only test the catch block, when there is actually an exception that is occurring, till then it cannot be tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the test cases that actually make the code to throw exception.
The control would go to the Catch Block and your coverage would increase.

For the test case to pass you can write the test case that would expect to get exception like

```
@Test(expected = CustomDefineException.class)
public void shouldThrowCustomDefineExceptionWhenWrongParameterIsSupplied() {
    // Your Logic to create Exception
    }
```

on the top of the test Method.

Comment: How would you expect the exception if you're catching it?

Comment: Aren't you throwing Your Custom Exception from catch. 
There is CustomDefineException in question.

Comment: I see what you mean. You should edit the answer with `expected = CustomDefineException.class` so it's not misleading.

Comment: Got Your point. Thank You. I have edited. 
If this solved your problem. Mark as answer

Comment: Btw I'm not the poster :)